# Is it grammatically correct to say, " I would let her know that you would join her "?

Tags: grammar, american-english, writing

I want to know if it’s grammatically correct to say, " I would let her know that you would join her "

Can you say this after asking someone if they would like to accompany another person out and they agree to do so.

Comment: Not "would" but "will" is the accurate word in this situation.

Comment: It's grammatically correct but no native speaker would says it – it sound very awkward. Also, it's not clear what the speaker's intention is: are they making a conditional statement, with the "if" clause omitted - and if so, which *would* does it apply to? Or is the first *would* intended to convey a recommendation? Goven the complexity of this seemingly benign set of words, the question probably belongs on [ell.se]. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suggest that they should contact her directly, your sentence is almost correct, but you need to add two words:

> I would let her know that you would **like to** join her

If your want to say that **you** will contact her, the sentence should be:

> I **will** let her know that you would **like to** join her

"I will... " means that you will do something.

"I would..." is a polite yet informal way of suggesting that you think that somebody else should do something.

"would like to..." is a polite way of expressing an interest in doing something.

You could replace "would like to" with "will", but that is less polite.

Comment: Not sure I agree with “‘will’ is less polite than ‘would like to’”. They mean different things. In this sentence, “Would like to” expresses a desire to do something ‘will’ expresses an intent to do it.  I will do it means I am going to do it. I would like to do it means doing it would make me happy.

Comment: @jim ... and it's more polite to say that it would make you happy to do something, than saying that you will do it, regardless or whether it makes you  happy.

Comment: I would like to go to the party but I need to do my homework.  I will go to the party but I need to be home by 11:00.